# An out of bounds index error when using Pytorch gather

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I have [Two Tensors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXIsq.jpg)

I am trying to gather one from each row with the column being specified by these indices. So I am trying to get:

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1]
```

This is my code for this:

```
self.manDistMat.gather(1, state.unsqueeze(-1)))
self.manDistMat
```

being the 16x16 matrix and `state.unsqueeze(-1)` being the other matrix.

When I try this I get this error.

> RuntimeError: index 578437695752307201 is out of bounds for dimension 1 with size 16

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured out it was cause I was indexing with a uint8 tensor. When I switched it to with .long() it worked. Can anyone explain why it has to be a long tensor?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the similar problem. It appears to be a [bug](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/37996) in pytorch.